# Django: Using prefetch_selected with get() and filter()

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-queryset

I am trying to make queries using prefetch_selected to prefetch many to many objects.
Using prefetch_selected when doing an *all()* query works okay but I do not know how i’m supposed to use it with *get()* or *filter()*. Here is my model:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    …
    funders = models.ManyToManyField(Organization, related_name="funders")

class Organization(models.Model):
    …
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
```

Trying the lines below doesn’t seem to work:

```
Project.objects.get(id=project_id).select_related('funders')
```

and

```
Project.objects.filter(id__in=[‘list-of-ids]).select_related('funders')
```

How i’m I supposed to go about it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You chained them in the wrong order, do it this way:

```
Project.objects.select_related('funders').get(id=project_id)
```

and

```
Project.objects.select_related('funders').filter(id__in=[‘list-of-ids])
```

You have to call `select_related` and `prefetch_related` on the **Manager** object (`Project.objects`).

Answer (score 1):

`select_related()` is a queryset method. The documentation on [querysets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/) has two sections of methods: methods that return a new queryset, and methods that do not return a queryset. `get()` is in the second section, so you can't chain any other queryset methods after it.

One other thing: `prefetch_related()` runs an extra query for each model. Since you're only fetching a single project, `project.funders.all()` will run exactly 1 query to fetch all related organizations regardless of your use of `prefetch_related()`. `prefetch_related` becomes useful when you need the related organizations for multiple projects.

Answer (score 0):

Since funder is m2m you cannot use select_related, you have to us prefetch instead. select_related only work on foreign key and one to one relation

```
Project.objects.prefetch_related('funders').filter(id__in=[id1, id2])
```